# Unexpected EOF when calling jpeg.Decode() on jpeg image

Tags: go, image-processing

I am trying to write a function that takes a string representing the name of an image and opens the image, or creates the image if it does not exist. Its supposed to return a pointer to the image file (so that it can be closed later) and a pointer to the pixel array of the image (for processing).

The code fails to decode the image and I cannot figure out why. As far as I can tell its a totally valid jpeg, right here on my computer. it also appears to fail only when the image exists, and doesn't seem to have a problem (or at least doesn't panic) when the image file does not exist.

```golang
package main

import (
    "image"
    "image/draw"
    "image/jpeg"
    "os"

    "log"
)

var (
    width  = 80
    height = 80
)

func main() {
    open("...")
}
func open(file string) (*os.File, *image.RGBA) {

    openedImage, err := os.Open(file)

    if err != nil {
        openedImage.Close()
        newImage, err := os.Create(file)
        check_error(err, "creating image")

        newImagePixels := image.NewRGBA(image.Rect(0, 0, width, height))

        return newImage, newImagePixels
    }

    // openedImage.Seek(0, 0)
    YCbCr, err := jpeg.Decode(openedImage) //   <--- unexpected EOF
    check_error(err, "decoding source image")

    bounds := YCbCr.Bounds()
    RGBA := image.NewRGBA(image.Rect(0, 0, bounds.Dx(), bounds.Dy()))
    draw.Draw(RGBA, RGBA.Bounds(), YCbCr, bounds.Min, draw.Src)

    return openedImage, RGBA
}

func check_error(err error, desc string) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("%v: %v", desc, err)
    }
}
```

I saw another post that was similar, which said that adding openedImage.Seek(0, 0) solved the problem, but that didn't work for me.

Comment: remove the line `openedImage.Seek(0, 0)` and test again

Comment: @janmbaco the output looks that same whether .Seek(0, 0) is there or not

Comment: I need more information, it's posible the image is empty. 
Give me the version of go and the image and I try to test myself

Comment: @janmbaco the image was empty, it must have been overwritten or something at some point while I was writing the code, but it definitely didn’t start empty. Thanks for responding so quickly and for the help

Comment: Remove  openedImage.Close() .

Comment: It would be useful to have a completely reproducible example. The code is not correct, though, it works.